# Pyinstaller .exe file does not open with Face_recognition module in it. (works in .py)

Tags: python, hook, pyinstaller, exe, face-recognition

I have wrote a code for face recognition in python.
My code works perfectly in `.py` file (without any errors or warning), but after making a `.exe` file out of it, through `pyinstaller` it won't work at all.
I have searched through, for the same and tried the following methods, but it still won't work.
first method i made the following changes in `.spec` file.
(Windows OS)

> main.spec file

```
block_cipher = None

face_models = [
('.\\face_recognition_models\\models\\dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
('.\\face_recognition_models\\models\\mmod_human_face_detector.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
('.\\face_recognition_models\\models\\shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
('.\\face_recognition_models\\models\\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
]

a = Analysis(['<your python script name.py>'],
             pathex=['<path to working directory>'],
             binaries=face_models,
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream', 'scipy', 'scipy.signal', 'scipy.signal.bsplines', 'scipy.special', 'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx',
                            'scipy.linalg.cython_blas',
                            'scipy.linalg.cython_lapack',
                            'scipy.integrate',
                            'scipy.integrate.quadrature',
                            'scipy.integrate.odepack',
                            'scipy.integrate._odepack',
                            'scipy.integrate.quadpack',
                            'scipy.integrate._quadpack',
                            'scipy.integrate._ode',
                            'scipy.integrate.vode',
                            'scipy.integrate._dop', 'scipy._lib', 'scipy._build_utils','scipy.__config__',
                            'scipy.integrate.lsoda', 'scipy.cluster', 'scipy.constants','scipy.fftpack','scipy.interpolate','scipy.io','scipy.linalg','scipy.misc','scipy.ndimage','scipy.odr','scipy.optimize','scipy.setup','scipy.sparse','scipy.spatial','scipy.special','scipy.stats','scipy.version'],

             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += Tree('./scipy-extra-dll', prefix=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='<your python script name>',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

another method

```
#replaced

datas=[]

#with

datas=[('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('mmod_human_face_detector.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat','./face_recognition_models/models')]
```

some people said it might me a problem with the `hook-scipy.py` file so here it is

> hook-scipy.py

```
import os
import glob
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_module_file_attribute
from PyInstaller.compat import is_win
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('scipy')

datas = collect_data_files('scipy')
binaries = []

# package the DLL bundle that official scipy wheels for Windows ship
# The DLL bundle will either be in extra-dll on windows proper
# and in .libs if installed on a virtualenv created from MinGW (Git-Bash
# for example)
if is_win:
    extra_dll_locations = ['extra-dll', '.libs']
    for location in extra_dll_locations:
        dll_glob = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
            get_module_file_attribute('scipy')), location, "*.dll")
        if glob.glob(dll_glob):
            binaries.append((dll_glob, "."))

# collect library-wide utility extension modules
hiddenimports = ['scipy._lib.%s' % m for m in [
    'messagestream', "_ccallback_c", "_fpumode"]]
```

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the above by doing this,

Changing the `data=[]` in the `main.spec` worked for me now I just pasted all this files `[('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('mmod_human_face_detector.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat','./face_recognition_models/models')]` 
in the same folder where my 'main.py' is present and then edited the `main.spec` and run the command `pyinstaller main.spec`.

Answer (score 0):

thank Siddhesh Khadapkar for this solution..
this is my app.spec

a = Analysis(

```
['app.py'],
pathex=[],
binaries=[],
datas=[('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('mmod_human_face_detector.dat','./face_recognition_models/models'),('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat','./face_recognition_models/models')],
hiddenimports=[],
hookspath=[],
hooksconfig={},
runtime_hooks=[],
excludes=['PyQt5'],
win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
win_private_assemblies=False,
cipher=block_cipher,
noarchive=False,
```

)

and i copying the file .dat model from face_recognition folder in python path to my project folder before i run .spec file